# FlatList not rendering style dynamically

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, native-base

I'm currently struggling in making my FlatList applying the changes I do to it. What I am wanting right now is that when I click an item in my flatlist, that it highlights in a certain color. I followed an approach done by a [guy](https://medium.com/@sudhirKr/how-to-highlight-and-multi-select-items-in-a-flatlist-component-react-native-1ca416dec4bc) but I am having the problem that to me is not working the update once I click.

I can see through console that all I am doing performs a modification but I think that I am missing some point with extraData parameter since it is not re-rendering with the backgroundColor that I would like to apply.

The code I have is as following, I know that the style I am applying is correct since if i substitute in the map styles.list per styles.selected, everything gets the background I would like to be applied to the elements I click.

So summarizing, the issue I think I have is that the flatlist is not re-rendering so it doesn't show the modifications I perform on it. Any idea of what I am doing wrong? Any tip?

```
 render() {

  const { students, studentsDataSource, loading, userProfile } = this.props.navigation.state.params.store;

  this.state.dataSource = studentsDataSource._dataBlob.s1.map(item => {
    item.isSelect = false;
    item.selectedClass = styles.list;
    return item;
  })
  const itemNumber = this.state.dataSource.filter(item => item.isSelect).length;
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Item rounded style={styles.searchBar}>
          <Input placeholder='Group Name'/>
        </Item>
        <FlatList
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            width: "100%",
          }}
          data={this.state.dataSource}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.FlatListItemSeparator}
          renderItem={ ({ item }) => (
              <ListItem avatar style={[styles.list, item.selectedClass]}
                onPress={() => this.selectItem(item)}>  
                  <Left>
                    {!item.voteCount &&  <Avatar unseen={true} /> }
                    {!!item.voteCount > 0 && <Avatar />}
                  </Left>
                  <Body>
                      <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                      <Text note>{item.group}</Text>
                  </Body>
              </ListItem>
            )
          }
          listKey={item => item.key}
          extraData={this.state}
        />
   </View>
  );
}
```

Here we can find the `state` and `SelectItem` functions:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            dataSource : [],
        }
    }

    //FlatListItemSeparator = () => <View style={styles.line} />;
    selectItem = data => {
      //{console.log("inside SelectItem=", data)}
      data.isSelect = !data.isSelect;
      data.selectedClass = data.isSelect? styles.selected: styles.list;
      const index = this.state.dataSource.findIndex( item => data.key === item.key);
      this.state.dataSource[index] = data;
      this.setState({
          dataSource: this.state.dataSource,
      });
      console.log("This state has the changes:=",this.state.dataSource)
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the main issue was that I was not using the .setState and instead I was doing assignations which killed the listeners.